# Android Kotlin - Why does a Seekbar minimum value over 100 not work?

Tags: java, android, android-studio, kotlin

Hello everybody When i add a min value to my Seekbar which is over 100 it always shows an min value of 100.
So for example my min value is 120 but it shows 120. I found out that i can use every value until 100 but no bigger value for my "min". Does anyone know the reason?

My code:

```
        myseekbar.min = 120
    myseekbar.max = 200
    
    myseekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
        override fun onProgressChanged(seekBar: SeekBar?, progress: Int, fromUser: Boolean) {
        }

        override fun onStartTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }

        override fun onStopTrackingTouch(seekBar: SeekBar?) {
        }
    })
```

Comment: have you tried setting the max first, instead of setting the min first? No idea about the internals of the progress bar, but since the default max is 100, I guess that it might not let you set the min over the max.

Comment: I just tried it. Unfortunately without success

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> `seekbar.min = 120`

Requires, API level 26 and above. If you test in a API level 26+, it should work fine.
Below is my code :

Kotlin

```
seekbar.max = 200
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.O) {
    seekbar.min = 120
}

seekbar.setOnSeekBarChangeListener(object : SeekBar.OnSeekBarChangeListener{
    override fun onProgressChanged(p0: SeekBar?, p1: Int, p2: Boolean) {
        seekbarValue.text = p1.toString()
    }
    override fun onStartTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}

    override fun onStopTrackingTouch(p0: SeekBar?) {}
})
```

XML

```
<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="horizontal">

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/seekbar_value"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"/>

</LinearLayout>
```

Output:

[Minimum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/J2Srp.png)

[Maximum](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GIeRx.png)